# random number from specific list of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

i need to create some lottery batch like

my list is 1 - 100 or it may vary to 1 - 200 or 1- 300

1. get 35 random numbers from these list.
2. get another 25 number from these list.
3. get another 10 number from these list.

only using Javascript.

Comment: Welcome on SO. What have you tried to far?

Comment: the first one i did but the rest list how will i create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function that I wrote, its comparing each random number to previous numbers to avoid duplicate and if you want to exclude some numbers (for example, previous attempts) you can pass them as exc to function.

```js
var lottery = function (min, max, size, exc) {
  var results = []
      , isDuplicate = false
      , random = 0;
  exc = exc || [];   
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    isDuplicate = true
    while (isDuplicate) {
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      if (results.indexOf(random) === -1 && exc.indexOf(random) === -1) {
        results.push(random);
        isDuplicate = false
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

var firstRun = lottery(1,100,35);
console.log(firstRun);
var secondRun = lottery(1,100,25,firstRun);
console.log(secondRun);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a very brief example, the script create a list of random number from 0 to 10 (you can change the number pool by passing a different value for arguments min/max  `getRandomInt(min, max)`.

Argument in `getNumbers(times)` specify how many time you want to pickup a number from the pool.

Please keep in mind that this example can pickup a number several time on different interaction (as this requirement is not mention in original question).

```js
(function() {
  var getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
  var getNumbers = function(times) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      console.log(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }
  };
  console.log('---------- Pickup 35 numbers');
  getNumbers(35);
  console.log('---------- Pickup 25 numbers');
  getNumbers(25);
  console.log('---------- Pickup 10 numbers');
  getNumbers(10);
})();
```

The following version pickup only unique numbers (as from your comment request):

```js
(function() {
  var usedNumbers = [];
  var getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
  var getNumbers = function(times) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      var number = getRandomInt(0, 100);
      if (usedNumbers.indexOf(number) === -1) {
        usedNumbers.push(number);
        console.log(number);
      }
    }
  };
  console.log('---------- Pickup 35 unique numbers');
  getNumbers(35);
  console.log('---------- Pickup 25 unique numbers');
  getNumbers(25);
  console.log('---------- Pickup 10 unique numbers');
  getNumbers(10);
})();
```

Comment: you did well , but can u see the list contains duplicate items. i want unique list :)

Comment: @MehboobSamnani ok it was not specified in your question :) let me edit my question ....

Comment: @MehboobSamnani I have edited my answer, I hope it solve your problem now :). If you found my answer useful please do not forget to accept it clicking the green arrow on its left side :) thanks!

Comment: by restricting the loops with time and ommitting the loop if there's a duplicate will reduce the length of list. can you see 35 is good , 25 maybe but in 10 they are not 10 elements.